# ExactTarget AMPscript - non-breakable content

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I need the content I pull in dynamically to do not break in email - is there any AMPscript function that I can use, something similar to Trim that we use for non-empty spaces?

Thanks. VD

Comment: Can you add more detail for what you are wanting to do?  Maybe add some code?

Comment: Hi Drew, I'm calling a variable @expirydate like this %%=v(@expirydate)=%% and I need the date to do not break, I need it to stay on the same row. How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Replace()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#Replace) function.  Like this:

```
%%=replace(@expirydate," ","&nbsp")=%%
```

Comment: that should work hehe. Thanks Adam, helpful as usual :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to prevent word wrap.  You may want to try [something like this](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-white-space/) in your html/css.

Comment: the data that is being pulled in has spaces Drew  - I know about white-space... Anyway Adam's solution is what I needed. Thanks both.